# How to respond to click on a table row in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I've got the following code:

```
public Button getBtnSubmit(com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener l) {
    if (null != l) {
        btnSubmit.addListener(l);
    }
    return btnSubmit;
}

public Table getTableCompany(HeaderClickListener hl) {
    if (null != hl) {
        tableCompany.addListener(hl);
    }
    return tableCompany;
}
```

**I would like to add a `listener` that fires when I select a (different) row in the table.**
This so that I can refresh some other controls with the table data, which listener should I use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`addListener` is deprecated now. Use the following instead.

```
table.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent itemClickEvent) {
        System.out.println(itemClickEvent.getItemId().toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I would go for `ItemClickListener`:

```
 table.addListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
               //implement your logic here
            }
        });
```

edit: For Vaadin 7+, use `addItemClickListener` method instead of `addListener`.

Comment: If you wish to get the id of the row clicked on then `Integer value = (Integer) event.getItem().getItemProperty("id").getValue();`

Comment: what about `event.getItemId()` ?

Comment: I believe itemId is different from id, I am speaking about a column that is hidden and whose value is used for processing at the backend.

Comment: This is now deprecated ib Vaadin 7, the answer from Ishan Thilina Somasiri is the correct one

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a [ValueChangeListener](https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.0/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#addValueChangeListener%28com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeListener%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ValueChangeListener don't forget to set

```
  table.setImmediate(true);
```

This means that the browser will report a change on selection immediately. If you don't set this your listener is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Read https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html, section 5.15.1 "Selecting Items in a Table".  You want to [add a Property.ValueChangeListener](https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.0/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#addValueChangeListener%28com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeListener%29).

Answer (score 0):

Many of these answers are both correct, and incorrect.

**If you need to get the selected items in response to the click, register a ValueChangeListener**.  Calling getValue() to retrieve the selection from the *ItemClickListener* might be 1 item behind in a MultiSelect list. For example, the set of items won't include/exclude the item triggering the callback.  You will not have a reference to the clicked item however.

If you simply want to **respond to a click on an item**, and do not need to consider the current selection state, **register an ItemClickListener** instead.  This way you will know what item was actually clicked.