# How to get clicked row number in table in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I need to get which row number user clicked to handle my database operations.

```
try {
        for (int i = 1; i < dbManager.getLastTopicId() + 1; i++) {

            Integer itemId = new Integer(i);
            String topicTitle = dbManager.getTitle(Integer.toString(i));
            String topicText = dbManager.getText(Integer.toString(i));
            String topicAuthor = dbManager.getAuthor(Integer.toString(i));

            topicList.addItem(new Object[] {topicTitle, topicText, topicAuthor},
                    itemId);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here I load data to topicList table.
I also use `topicList.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event)`
To handle users click. But I need to get from that Listener, which row number did user clicked. I have tried `topicList.getValue()` and stuff but non of them returns me row number.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get your row id by either adding a `ValueChangeListener` or a `ItemClickListener`.
Note: The ItemClickListener doesn't respond to keyboard arrow up or arrow down, only ValueChangeListener does.

With the EventObject you get access to the item id.

```
Table table = new Table();
table.setImmediate(true);
table.setSelectable(true);
table.addListener(new ValueChangeListener() { // With ValueChangeListener respons to keyboard input as well

    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        getMainWindow().showNotification("ValueChange: ItemId: " + event.getProperty().getValue());
    }
});
table.addListener(new ItemClickListener() { // With ItemClickListener

    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
        getMainWindow().showNotification("ItemClick: ItemId" + event.getItemId());
    }
});
```

In Vaadin7 method names has changed to:

```
table.addValueChangeListener();
table.addItemClickListener();
```

Comment: Note: if a table has multi-select enabled, then the value change can/will be a collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to track clicks, you could add an `ItemClickListener` to the table using [addItemClickListener()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#addItemClickListener%28com.vaadin.event.ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener%29). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14687137/210380).

If you want to read the value of the table, maybe with multiselect, you could use `ValueChangeListener` as you already do and read the ids with [getValue()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSelect.html#getValue%28%29)